# Help me identify this science fiction graphic novel involving spacefaring mice/rats that I read in 2013

Tags: story-identification, comics, childrens-novel, soft-sci-fi

I have been looking for the name of this sci-fi graphic novel that I read in 2013. I do not remember the name of the novel, only a brief summary of the story.

Here it goes:

> The story is set on board a spaceship full of intelligent spacefaring mice/rats. They live as nomads, exploring the galaxy and making contact with large numbers of alien civilizations. One day, the mice/rats encounter a planet full of pink colored mice/rats that look and act identically to them except for their color. They claim to contact them in peace and the spacefaring creatures spend one day with them. After the spaceship departs the planet, the nomads learn the truth about them. They are parasitic and invade the ship. One characters traps them into a mint box and seals it shut. The box is then ejected from the ship into space and the book concludes.

It appeared to be a children's book targeted towards middle school students based on the content and writing level.

From what I remember, the book was part of a series of books also featuring the same spacefaring entities. I did not read the other books in the series, so I can't give you plots from other books to help you identify it.

The series appears to be rather indie and not well known, since I couldn't find anything after checking the major sites such as Goodreads to see if they have information about a graphic novel series featuring anthropomorphic mice/rats.

Comment: “It appeared to be a children's book targeted towards middle school students” — teaching them the vital lesson that if you see people who are a different colour to you, you should eject them into space immediately 

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, I know. It's borderline racist, but I still want to find out the name of the book.

Comment: In fairness to this book that I’ve not read, it might be fine in context. I’m very much on board with the idea of spacefaring mice, it sounds adorable.

Comment: I immediately thought of "sugar mice", it was the mint box that brought them to mind. I haven't seen them in years but they were a hard sweet made of white sugar, shaped like a mouse with a piece of string for a tail that could be used to hang them from a christmas tree. I only mention them because I don't know if they were a particularly UK confection and whether this could help source the story.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "sugar mice." As far as I remember, it was only the mints that were a part of the story.